# Не работает игра, вроде делал по учебнику(только учу)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка 
**Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 231, in  main() File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 213, in main computer.human = pieces() File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 106, in pieces return computer.human AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'human'**

```
# Инструкция
# Создание функции

def instructions():
    """ Выводит на экран инструкцию для игрока"""
    print(
        """Добро пожаловать на ринг грандиознейших интелектуальных состязаний всех времен.
           Твой мозг и мой процессор сойдуться в схватке за доской игры'Крестики-нолики'.
           Чтобы сделать ход,введи число от 0 до 8. Числа однозначно соотвествуют полям 
           доски - так, как показано ниже:

           0 | 1 | 2
           ----------
           3 | 4 | 5 
           ----------
           6 | 7 | 8

           Приготовтесь к бою, жалкий кусок мяса. Вот вот начнется решающие сра-
           жение\n   """
           )


# main part
print ("Это инструкция для игры в 'Крестики-нолики': ")
instructions()
print ("Это опять таже самая инструкция вдруг ты не понял еще этого: ")
instructions()
print("Надеюсь теперь смысл ясен")
input ("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")

#========================================================
# Крестики-Нолики
# Компьютер играет в крестики нолики против пользователя
# глобальные константы
#========================================================


X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "Ничья"
NUM_SQUARES = "9"

#========================================================
# Крестики-Нолики
# Компьютер играет в крестики нолики против пользователя
# Функции
#========================================================


def display_instruct():
    """Выводит на экран инструкцию для игрока"""
    print("""
        Добро пожаловать на ринг грандиознейших интелектуальных состязаний всех вре-
        мен.
        Твой мозг и мой процессор сойдутся в поединке.
        Чтобы сделать ход,введи число от 0 до 8. Числа однозначно соотвествуют полям 
        доски - так, как показано ниже:

        0 | 1 | 2
        ----------
        3 | 4 | 5 
        ----------
        6 | 7 | 8

        Приготовтесь к бою, жалкий кусок мяса. Вот вот начнется решающие сра-
        жение\n   """)


def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Задает вопрос Да или Нет"""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y","n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response


def ask_number(question,low,high):
    """Просит ввести число из диапозона"""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low,high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response


def pieces():
    """Определяет принадлежность первого хода"""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Хочешь отсавить за собой первый хпд? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print ("\nНу что ж, даю тебе фору: играй крестиками. ")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print ("\nТвоя удаль тебя погубит... Буду начинать я.")
        computer = X
        human =O    
    return computer.human


def new_board():
    """Создает новую игровую доску"""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board


def display_board():
    """Отображает игровую доску на экране"""
    print ("\n\t" ,board[0], "|" ,board[1], "|" ,board[2])
    print ("\t","----------")
    print ("\t" ,board[3], "|" ,board[4], "|" ,board[5])
    print ("\t","----------")
    print ("\t" ,board[6], "|" ,board[7], "|" ,board[8])


def legal_moves():
    """Создает список доступных кодов"""
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves


def winner():
    """Определяет победителя в игре"""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0,1,2),
                    (3,4,5),
                    (6,7,8),
                    (0,3,6),
                    (1,4,7),
                    (2,5,8),
                    (0,4,8),
                    (2,4,6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[low[0]] == board[low[1]] == board[low[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[low[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
        else:
            return None


def human_move(board, human):
    """Получает ход человека"""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Твой ход. Выбери одно из полей (0 - 8): " ,0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nСмешной человек! Это поле уже занято. Выбери другое.\n")
    print ("Ладно...")
    return move

def computer_move(board,computer,human):
    """Делает ход ИИ"""
    board = board[:]
    BEST_MOVES = (4,0,2,6,8,1,3,5,7)
    print ("Я выберу поле номер", end=" ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move


def next_turn(turn):
    """Осуществляет переход хода"""
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X


def congrat_winner(the_winner,computer,human):
    """Поздравляет победителя игры"""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print("Три",the_winner,"в ряд!\n")
    else:
        print ("Ничья")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("Как я и говорил ты жалкий кусок мяса")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print("Хммм ты точно человек? Как ты смог выйграть меня")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("Тебе просто повезло, мы сыграли в ничью!")


def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer.human = pieces()
    turn = X    
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board,human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board,computer,human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner,computer,human)


#Запуск программы
main()
input("\nНажмите Enter чтобы выйти. ")
```

Comment: опишите пожалуйста что именно у вас вызвало затруднение, просто листинга кода не достаточно

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 213, in main
    computer.human = pieces()
  File "C:/Users/artli/Desktop/XO.py", line 106, in pieces
    return computer.human
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'human'

Comment: сойдуТСя. приготоВЬтесь. (на всякий случай поправляю, вдруг игра популярной станет, орфография должна быть на 5)

Comment: Обожаю этих людей которые рады поправить орфографические ошибки. Если бы я пришел за этим, то обратился бы не на этот сайт. А помощь мне нужна в работе кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
computer.human = pieces()
```

Заменить на

```
computer, human = pieces()
```

Функция pieces() возвращает две строки computer и human соответственно. Ошибка вызвана тем, что данный код пытается присвоить результат выполнения функции свойству human у объекта computer. В данном случае computer является строкой и естественно не содержит такого поля.

Тоже самое необходимо сделать и в теле функции pieces() для строки

```
return computer.human
```

Тут должно быть

```
return computer, human
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artli\Desktop\XO.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\artli\Desktop\XO.py", line 215, in main
    board = new_board()
  File "C:\Users\artli\Desktop\XO.py", line 112, in new_board
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Должно быть так `NUM_SQUARES = 9` он ругается на то, что там строка вместо инт-а

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artli\Desktop\XO.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\artli\Desktop\XO.py", line 216, in main
    display_board(board)
TypeError: display_board() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given (а тут?) я понимаю что у меня может быть много ошибок и очень благодарен за ответы

Comment: `def display_board():` -> `def display_board(board):`

Ошибка вызвана тем, что в функцию передается аргументом board, а при ее объявлении ни указано ни одного аргумента.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, у меня все равно вылазят ошибки я лучше попробую сам все перепроверить. Спасибо огромное